# Merge other java Server code to Spring boot code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some legacy java code which has tcp server and sends JSON data to some call back .

And have  other spring a server which is working for current generation application which receives the data from clients,validates, persist and sends to other stake holders .

So now I need to have same features for my legacy code but due to internal and legacy formats I can not rewrite in spring. I am looking to merge that legacy tcp server and my spring utilities  written (validation,persist etc), I am using all spring features like @Auto-wired, @component, @Service and @repository etc so how to use that tcp server along with these features.